# Interactive pop gesture on ios6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uikit

I'm currently in love with the interactive pop gesture in ios7. Is there any possibility (or existing example) of this functionality over ios6?

Cheers

Comment: There were some jailbreak tools which introduced this behavior, but I am not aware of any way using the system-provided classes. If you create a navigation controller of your own (or subclass the system one and implement transitions yourself), this is possible.

Comment: Apple strongly recommends on their guidelines to not mimic iOS 7 UI features on iOS 6. It could cause confusion on users. I think it is a very wise recommendation.

Comment: You can add a gesture recognizer on top of the UINavigationBar, but as @RogielSulzbach said, focus on making the iOS 7 app, not its backward-compatible version.

Comment: Another thing to consider is - how will users even know to perform this gesture? It is not native to iOS6, while it is on iOS7 and users expect it.

Comment: Currently working on a task manager, which will have a "paged" structure. That or similar effect is essential to the current functionality; will also be described in the tutorial.